# How to write changes to file in awk END statement

Tags: bash, awk, substring, substitution

I'm substituting some string with this "bash" script where I use awk features.
Can I somehow save the changes to a file in the END statement? or is this not
how things are done with awk. Or would you recommend using a combination of grep and sed instead?

```
 #!/usr/bin/bash
 
 
 FILENAME=$1
 SUBSTRING=$2
 
 
 echo $FILENAME 
 
 cat $FILENAME | awk '
 BEGIN {
         IGNORECASE=1
         foundinput=0
 };
 
 
 {
 if (foundinput={
         if ($0 ~ /INPUT/){
                 start=match($0, /\/.*$/)
                 SUBTHIS=substr($0, start)
                 sub(SUBTHIS, "'$SUBSTRING'")
                 print($0)
         }   
 }
 }
 
 {gsub(" ", "", $0)}
 b=/BRAKEDISC/
 
 {
 if (b={
         foundinput=1
 };
 }
 
 END {
         print $0 > "input.bak"
 }
 '
```

I'll appreciate any advice.

cheers,
Christopher

Comment: You will need to add the lines as values to an in memory array and then loop through the array and print the lines to the file in the END section. Also you don't need to pipe cat through to awk, use awk '{...}' filename. Seems like you may just need awk '{...}' filename > input.bak without the END section.

Comment: Please also add a small example of your input file along with the desired result

Comment: Hello Raman, that worked fine for me! thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello jas, unfortunately I can't do that with this specific file, I could prepare some dummy file later that day, if that helps?

Comment: What is `if (foundinput={ ... ` supposed to do? Is there some awk variant in which that is valid syntax?

Comment: There are several instances where /INPUT/ is defined, so this was my way to only match the one, whose previous line also matches something else. This could probably be done more elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks as if you don't need an END block. You just need to redirect the output to input.bak and so:

```
awk '{...}' filename > input.bak
```